Login page can't correctly direct to secret page
I am trying to build a simple sign up page and login page. Here is my code below
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const User = require("./models/user")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const saltRounds = 10;
require('dotenv').config()


app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cookieParser ("This is my secret"))
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized:false,

}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))



app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
  console.log(process.env.SECRET)
  res.send("welcome to homepage")
})  

app.get("/signup",(req, res)=>{
  res.render("signup")
})

app.post("/signup", (req,res, next)=>{
  let {username, password} = req.body
  bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err, salt)=>{
    if (err){
      next(err)
    }
    console.log(salt)
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash)=>{
      let newUser = new User({username, password})
      try{
        newUser.save().then(()=>{
          console.log(req.body)
          res.send("data has been saved")
        }).catch((e)=>{
          res.send("error")
          console.log(e)
        })
      }catch(e){
        next(e)
      }
    })
    })
  })
  
  

app.get("/login", (req,res)=>{
  res.render("login")
})


app.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  let { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    let foundUser = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!foundUser) {
      res.send("User not found");
    } else {
      const isMatch = bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        res.send("Password incorrect");
      } else {
        // Password is correct, render the secret page
        res.render("secret");
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});



app.get("/*", (req, res)=>{
  res.status(404).send("404 page not found")
})


//global error settintg
app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{
  console.log(err)
  res.status(500).send("Something wrong happened")
})

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/studentDB').then(()=>{
    console.log("U success")
}).catch(e =>{
    console.log("connection failed");
    console.log(e);
})
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3000.");
});


What I have found is that at the phase of
app.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  let { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    let foundUser = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!foundUser) {
      res.send("User not found");
    } else {
      const isMatch = bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        res.send("Password incorrect");
      } else {
        // Password is correct, render the secret page
        res.render("secret");
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});

whether the password is correct or not , it can still get to the secret page
Then I ask chatgpt, it told me to add await before bcrypt.compare looks like
app.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  let { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    let foundUser = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!foundUser) {
      res.send("User not found");
    } else {
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        res.send("Password incorrect");
      } else {
        // Password is correct, render the secret page
        res.render("secret");
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});

The sign up page works well it returns "data has been saved" and console correct username and password. such as username:example@gmail.com password: 1234
Then I checked the console at login page
It returns exactly the same thing that at the sign up page
but it turns to return password incorrect whether the password is correct or not

Reading the docs you should use bcrypt compare function like:
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result) {
  if (err){
    return false;
  }
  if (result) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // response is OutgoingMessage object that server response http request
    return false;
  }
});

So you can handling errors or handling password doesn't match and send the response to the users
